# SceneKit Floor Texture Changed Color in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit, xcode8

I have a floor in my SceneKit scene that is suppose to be green based on the texture I have selected for its diffuse property. It worked perfectly in Xcode 7, however, in Xcode 8 it is red and shows up on my device as gray. Here are some screenshots below that help explain this better:

[image: What the floor looked like in Xcode 7]

[image: What the floor now looks like in Xcode 8]

[image: Current floor properties in Xcode 8]

Any and all help is great appreciated.

Comment: The first image is what the floor looked like in Xcode 7. The second image is what the floor currently looks like in Xcode 8. The third image is the floor’s properties in Xcode 8..

Comment: how did you fix this?

Comment: How did you add Grass.png in the diffuse property?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose this is because your image has a single color channel and SceneKit handles it a R8 texture. Try converting it to RGB (what SceneKit was doing in iOS 9/Xcode7 anyway).
And please file a bug.

Comment: I am confused as to what you mean by this. I do not do a lot of work with textures. All I did was create a simple PNG in gimp and dragged that into Xcode. All other PNG textures work that are in the project, however, those were exported from a program called MagicaVoxel that makes voxel models.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across with the same problem and fixed that issue with using JPEG file instead PNG. That might be related with a bug in xCode 8